# Compare two json files on windows machine

Tags: java, json

I want to compare two json file on windows. Suggest some tools. 
The result of the comparision should the differences in two json files.

Comment: Not relevant question, this forum is about issues with java programming, not about windows tools... Use google to find windows tools for comparing documents

Comment: Why specifically windows??

Comment: I want a sample java program which compares json

Comment: Another neat online tool: http://benjamine.github.io/jsondiffpatch/demo/index.html

Comment: Another online tool: http://json-diff.com

Comment: There is also python tools:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/json_tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [JSON Diff](http://tlrobinson.net/projects/javascript-fun/jsondiff/). This is online tool.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah may simply select both files -if you have them added to a project/plug-in in eclipse- and choose "Compare...->Each other"

Comment: what if the element of json in both files are not in same line

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Internet sites for the same are.. :-

1)http://www.prettydiff.com/
2)http://tlrobinson.net/projects/javascript-fun/jsondiff